# How to add skin to ckeditor in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I've to install CKEditor in my Rails project but the buttons on the default skin are all misaligned. See:

[image]

So I'm trying to install the Bootstrap skin to fix this and also because it fits better with the rest of my website.

I've downloaded the files and put under

```
app/assets/ckeditor/skins/bootstrapkg
```

And changed config/ckeditor.rb to add:

```
  config.asset_path = Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
```

But when I try to add the method config.assets_skins or config.skins I get

```
NoMethodError:: undefined method `skin=' for Ckeditor:Module
```

I've tried config.skins, config.skinName but nothing works.

When I try to create a app/assets/ckeditor/config.js and put

```
config.skin = 'bootstrapkg';
```

... the editor stops showing.

In my rails server log, I can still see calls for the 'moono' skin instead of the Bootstrap one.

So, how do I install another theme to CKEditor on Rails (I can also accept a fix for the misaligned buttons)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I even tried to contact support from CKEditor but had no luck.

Comment: After seeing how many files the skin had (CKEditor is a huge beast) I decided to not include the skin.

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: It has been some time since I worked on that particular project. A few months after I posted the question the error was still happening.

Comment: Apparently you should be able to put the skin in `vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/[[skin-folder]]` but I am yet to have luck with this

Comment: check if correct css is loading in background call when you open the ckeditor page with misaligned buttons, check network tab of chrome browser's inspector/developer tools

Comment: have you precompiled your assets?

Answer (score 1):

the thing here is that you need to place the skin folder on the public folder and not in the assets folder because it will be precompiled and will have the timestamp in the name, so when ckeditor try to get the file at `app/assets/ckeditor/skins/bootstrapkg`, the file has the name of `bootstrapkg1234354` you get the point. So, place the skin folder on

```
/public/assets/ckeditor/skins/
```

and then on your file `/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` you can add simply

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ){

  config.skin = 'bootstrapkg';

};
```

or the skin you want to add and that's all, it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The name is incorrect.  You have this

```
config.skin = 'bootstrapkg';
```

It should be this

```
config.skin = 'bootstrapck';
```

Place inside a folder called `skins` at this location `/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins` and it should work.

So the path to the bootstrap skin folder should be `/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/skins/bootstrapck`.